# Prometheus metrics do not disapper after being deleted

Tags: prometheus

I need to delete some Prometheus metrics originating from one host. For simplicity let's assume all metrics from the host need to be deleted.

Executed POST to a `delete_series` endpoint on both VMs. Got 204 as expected. The metrics did not disappear (still visible in web / browser interface, even after forcing cache refresh via `CTRL+R`, `CTRL+F5`).

Also tried forcing `clean_tombstones`, got 204, but not change.

Restarted both instances, then also waited a day in a hope that "something" will reload itself.

The commands used:
`# curl -X POST -g 'http://localhost:9090/api/v1/admin/tsdb/delete_series?match[]={instance="my-hostname"}' -v`

`# curl -X POST -g 'http://localhost:9090/api/v1/admin/tsdb/clean_tombstones' -v`

The output:

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 9090 (#0)
> POST /api/v1/admin/tsdb/delete_series?match[]={instance="my-hostname"} HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:9090
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Authorization, Content-Type, Origin
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, OPTIONS
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Date
< Date: Tue, 23 Jul 2019 07:54:30 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

My Prometheus cluster consists of two VMs running Prometheus 2.6.1.

`admin-api` is enabled:

```
           └─28557 /opt/prometheus/prometheus-server/prometheus --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml --storage.tsdb.path=/data/prometheus/databases --storage.tsdb.retention=15d --web.enable-admin-api --web.external-url=http://redacted --log.level=debug
```

Comment: "still visible in web / browser interface" - where exactly? Are you still ingesting metrics with these labels?

Comment: @brian-brazil both in the "graph" (when queried for `metricName{instance="my-hostname"}`) and "alerts" tabs. No, I'm not ingesting new metrics with this particular set of labels.

Comment: That sounds like a bug then, but before filing it please check you've no typos etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon further inspection it turned out that there was an unexpected node-exporter file in `/var/spool/prometheus` directory on the source host causing node-exporter to re-**scrape** ancient metrics over and over again. After deleting the file and re-running the delete command the metrics are gone.