# How to configurate prometheus.yml to scrape only running containers for node-exporter

Tags: docker, prometheus, grafana, docker-swarm, prometheus-node-exporter

I have a problem with the grafana/prometheus when I used `node-exporter` to collect host's resources from docker swarm nodes.

I tested with only one swarm node. When I used the query
`label_values(node_uname_info{job="node-exporter"}, instance)` in Grafana variables. The result returned **the old ip of stopped containers and the ips of running container** as well. I want it only returns the ip of running container. You can see the image below, it shows the ip of node-exported containers all the time.

[image]

But actually, one one container is running with the ip 10.0.1.12:9100. The other ips were the old ip of node-exporter containers that started and stopped. Here is the time-series that these contianer were created.
[image]

I think we can configurate the scrape method in prometheus.yml with the #relabel_config but I am not familiar with it. Here is the scrape method I got from https://github.com/stefanprodan/swarmprom.

```
  - job_name: 'node-exporter'
    dns_sd_configs:
    - names:
      - 'tasks.node-exporter'
      type: 'A'
      port: 9100
```

Do you know how to filter the only running containers by adding some attribute in prometheus.yml. Thank you so much for your consideration.

Comment: Can you give n examples of the metrics you get from prometheus how you get them now and what you expect?

Comment: Do you mean "IP of **stopped node**" instead of *stopped container* ? The node-exporter allows you to get metrics about your node. Your Grafana query returns your hosts IP. If you want metrics about containers, you need to use **cadvisor**

Comment: Hi @MarcABOUCHACRA, I added the image above. Could you please look at it again? I mean the ip of the container

Comment: Hmm... I guess you're running the node-exporter as a docker container then ? Because, as i've said, node-exporter is about the node, not containers. But running it as a docker container (which is deprecated) might be the cause to your problem.

Comment: So I should run the node-exporter locally in the every node instead.

Comment: Yes this is the recommended usage (cf [the documentation](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter#docker) ). But that does not tell us why you're still seeing old IP, this is probably related to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57160635/prometheus-metrics-do-not-disapper-after-being-deleted) but it can be anything else. We need more info on your container settings to help you out

Comment: the question is, are you interested in only the latest (the running instance) or are you interested in all instance, but just dont want to select the instances. And is there only one instance runnin all the time or are there multiple instances running at the same time?

Comment: First of all, the observed behaviour is completely correct, in the past the container had another IP address.

Comment: @MarcABOUCHACRA, I think I saw the old ip because the metrics logs were already stored some places in prometheus container or grafana(I am not sure at this point)

Comment: @JensBaitinger I think it is better to see the resource all time, not distinct or split every time the container was stopped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the last comment, you can modify the queries using the following pattern:

```
min ignoring (instance) (<query without instance>)
```

so the (example) query

```
rate(cpu_time_seconds{instance="$instance", otherLabel="otherValue"}[5m])
```

becomes

```
min without (instance) (rate(cpu_time_seconds{otherLabel="otherValue"}[5m])
```

The aggregation function is relatively irrelevant here, as you only have one value at a time.

Additionally you can remove the `instance` variable from the dashboard